# Vue + Laravel: Including fonts in Single Vue Components

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a laravel project where I am using single view components.  I have a global.scss file where I have code below to include my fonts which are placed in public/fonts folder.  In the style section of each vue component , I am using `@import '../../css/global.scss';` to import the global.scss file but the fonts still dont seem to be usable.  Am I doing anything wrong with this setup?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Testing-Font';
    src: url('/public/fonts/Avenir-Black.tff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Avenir-Light';
    src: url('/public/fonts/Avenir-Light.tff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Test-Fontname';
    src: url('/public/fonts/Avenir-Book.tff');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming `public` is the director from which the web page is served, you should probably omit it from the font files paths:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Testing-Font';
    src: url('/fonts/Avenir-Black.tff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Avenir-Light';
    src: url('/fonts/Avenir-Light.tff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Test-Fontname';
    src: url('/fonts/Avenir-Book.tff');
}
```

to see if something went wrong with the loading process, open the *network* tab of your favored browser's dev-tools, and look for `40x` errors.

if the issue persist (and stems from `404` errors), try and use a relative path for the font files, to avoid any unknowns when your build system resolves the root path (`/`).

also, depending on the use case (library/application) i would include it in the entrypoint file, so any component could use it.

Comment: the page gets served from `public/dist/js/app.js` and the fonts are in `public/fonts/` . I just checked the network tab and i see 404 errors for the fonts when using 'public' in the path and even when removing it.

Comment: well, than try to use a relative path to the font files instead (i'll update my answer accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

Either your font files have wrong extension or you just typed extension wrong in CSS. It should be `ttf`, not `tff`.